# MySQL / MariaDB partitioning for Laravel softdeleteable (deleted_at IS NULL vs datetime value)

Tags: mysql, mariadb, partitioning

A Laravel Eloquent *softdeleteable* (sometimes called *softdeletable*) table looks like this:

`id | value1 | value2 | ... | valueN | deleted_at`

and `deleted_at` will be `null` for active entries and a datetime value for deleted entries.

Is it achievable / advisable to partition the InnoDB table into active versus deleted records?

(meaning a partition for all null values and another one for any actual value)

Update:  After a bit of research, here's the partitioning I came up with:

```
ALTER TABLE `listings`
PARTITION BY RANGE( UNIX_TIMESTAMP(deleted_at) )
SUBPARTITION BY HASH( user_id )
SUBPARTITIONS 40
(
    PARTITION active VALUES LESS THAN (0), -- null values (not deleted rows) will go here
    PARTITION deleted VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE -- non-null values (deleted rows) will go here
);
```

Update 2:
Users will never be softdeleted.  Listings will.  They will eventually accumulate more deleted listings than active ones.
Users can define and combine any number on filters in any column (in an excel fashion).
`user_id` and `deleted_at < 0` (which will prune partitions while `IS NULL` won't, according to `EXPLAIN PARTITIONS`) will always be present in the query.
I figured that partitioning would always reduce the count of rows to examine, and sometimes the query would benefit from using one of the remaining indexes.  I'm not sure I was correct about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PARTITIONing` rarely helps with performance.

This

```
WHERE deleted_at IS NULL
  AND ...
```

Would benefit from a composite index:

```
INDEX(deleted_at, ...)
```

Where the "..." parts match in some way.

(Note this works because `IS NULL` works like `=`.  That is, such an index would *not* help when saying `deleted_at IS NOT NULL`.  And such would not be very useful in `deleted_at BETWEEN ... AND ...`.)

Show us a few *real* queries; there may be further tips to share.

Indexes if not using partitioning:

```
PRIMARY KEY(user_id, id), -- perfect for finding one user
INDEX(id)   -- to keep auto_increment happy
```

If `user_id` is unique, the get rid of `id` completely.

Do you need to find all (or search among) deleted users?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215919/discussion-on-answer-by-rick-james-mysql-mariadb-partitioning-for-laravel-soft).